# Get link name with request.args in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Is it possible to give a name to a `<a>` tag which href attribute is redirect to another part of my page, and use this name to access at request.args in Flask? Or it only works with forms and `<input>` tags?

```
    {% extends 'base_template.html' %}
    {% block content %}
        <h2>Cities</h2>
        {% for c in cities %}
            <p><a name={{c["name"]}} href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/">{{c["name></p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

I'm trying something like this but when I click in the link to redirect to the main page

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    print(request.args)
    if request.args.get('search') != None:
        search = request.args.get('search')
        return redirect(url_for('search', city=search))

    r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/resorts/')
    return render_template('principal.html', resorts=json.loads(r.text))
```

request.args its empty and I was wondering if there is a way to know that this link was pressed.

Comment: Can you please give the relevant code example? It's hard to tell exactly from the description you have given.

Comment: @metatoaster Sorry I edited the post, thanks for the reply tho.

Comment: Based on how you have defined the route, you need your browser to access `http://127.0.0.1/?search=City`, and to do that, the template should include this `<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/city={{ c['name'] }}">{{ c['name'] }}</a>` in the for loop.